# LocalDateTime sets calculate overlap in seconds

Tags: java, algorithm

I am attempting to determine the amount of time in seconds two sets of dates overlap. If the dates do not overlap, my method would return 0.

```
@Test
public void calculateOverlapInSeconds() {

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    // Larger window of time
    LocalDateTime startTime1 = now.minusSeconds(15);
    LocalDateTime endTime1 = now.plusSeconds(15);

    // Smaller window of time
    LocalDateTime startTime2 = now.minusSeconds(5);
    LocalDateTime endTime2 = now.plusSeconds(5);

    long i = getOverlapInSeconds(startTime2, endTime2, startTime1, endTime1);

    Assert.assertEquals(i, 10);
}
```

I was trying to follow this article: https://wmfexcel.com/2014/10/25/how-to-calculate-number-of-overlapping-days-for-two-periods/

```
public long getDifferenceInSeconds(LocalDateTime startTime2, LocalDateTime endTime2, LocalDateTime startTime1, LocalDateTime endTime1) {

    LocalDateTime minStartTime = (startTime2.isBefore(startTime1) ? startTime2 : startTime1);
    LocalDateTime minEndTime = (endTime2.isBefore(endTime1) ? endTime2 : endTime1);

    long seconds = minStartTime.until(minEndTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    return seconds > 0 ? seconds : 0;
}
```

This does not currently work. How do I calculate the time overlap in seconds between 2 date sets?

**Updated Working Code:**

```
public long getDifferenceInSeconds(LocalDateTime startTime2, LocalDateTime endTime2, LocalDateTime startTime1, LocalDateTime endTime1) {

    LocalDateTime maxStartTime =
            startTime2.isAfter(startTime1) ? startTime2 : startTime1;
    LocalDateTime minEndTime = (endTime2.isBefore(endTime1) ? endTime2 : endTime1);

    long seconds = maxStartTime.until(minEndTime, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    return seconds > 0 ? seconds : 0;
}
```

Comment: "This does not currently work." - Your test passes for me.

Comment: @JacobG. I updated the example. Now the result should be 10 because the smaller window is within the larger window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your code inside `getDifferenceInSeconds` gets the earliest starting time, but you want to use the latest start time.  You can change the following:

```
LocalDateTime minStartTime = 
     (startTime2.isBefore(startTime1) ? startTime2 : startTime1);
```

To:

```
LocalDateTime maxStartTime = 
     startTime2.isAfter(startTime1) ? startTime2 : startTime1;
```